# Wordpress different headers on each pages

Tags: php, wordpress

is it possible to have different headers on each page?
I'm currently using this code which works perfectly

```
<?php if(is_front_page()):?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[myiamge1]'); ?>

<?php endif;?>
```

Now I tried to use this code and it doesnt work

```
<?php if(is_front_page()):?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[myiamge1]'); ?>

else { ?> (is_page('Contact')){
echo '<img src="image5.jpg" />';
}

<?php endif;?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: that doesn't look like vaid php.... some weird mismatching of tags

Comment: i meant `valid` not `vaid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about `Wordpress` - never used it but the above doesn't look right. Is there a reason whya more traditional style syntax is not adopted - more akin to this:

```
<?php
    if( is_front_page() ){
        echo do_shortcode('[myiamge1]');
    } elseif( is_page('Contact') ){
        echo '<img src="image5.jpg" />';
    } else {
        /*banana for scale - do something else*/
    }
?>
```